# Proof that MAX CLIQUE is NP-Hard

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard, decision-problem, np

My question is simple: does any body know where can I find the proof that MAX CLIQUE is NP-HARD?

**Remarks:**

MAX CLIQUE is the decision problem defined as follows:Given a graph $G$ and $k>0$. Does the graph $G$ contain a maximum clique of size $k$?

I have been looking for a formal proof that MAX CLIQUE is **NP-Hard**, still I haven't found one. The book of Computers and Intractability (Michael Garey) in the final chapters mentions briefly that the full proof is on the phd thesis of Ernet Legget: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=907661 . I couldn't find the copy of the book on the internet nor any survey whit the proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is probably a proof in Karp's original paper. Here is a simple reduction from SAT. Given an instance $\varphi$ of SAT with $m$ clauses, construct an instance of MAX-CLIQUE as follows. For each clause $C$ and each literal $\ell$ appearing in $C$, there is a vertex $(C,\ell)$. Two vertices $(C_1,\ell_1),(C_2,\ell_2)$ are connected if $C_1 \neq C_2$ and $\ell_1 \neq \lnot \ell_2$. This has a clique of size $m$ iff $\varphi$ is satisfiable (exercise).

Comment: I studied this proof for the CLIQUE  problem which is a bit different from MAX CLIQUE but of course the same proof works for the MAX CLIQUE :) I can't believe that i could not see that!! THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

The standard reduction from SATISFIABILITY to CLIQUE is outlined in Karp's classic paper, see page 97.

- Richard M. Karp, [*Reducibility among Combinatorial Problems*](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~luca/cs172/karp.pdf), In *Proceedings of a symposium on the Complexity of Computer Computations*, 1972, pp.85–103. doi:[10.1007/978-1-4684-2001-2_9](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4684-2001-2_9)

Comment: Presumably it's the very same reduction appearing in my answer.

Comment: Of course!  In fact I'd be quite interested in any other natural reductions.